# Matrix multiplication using Parallel Processing

Tags: python, matrix, parallel-processing, matrix-multiplication

I want to create a python code that multiply matrices using Mesh Network algorithm,
the output is not as expected because the more number of processors(cores) is passed, the slower the algorithm.
this is my code(I utilized Google Colab to run this code):

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import random
import numpy as np

def generate_random_matrix(rows, cols):
    return [[random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(cols)] for _ in range(rows)]

def sequential_matrix_multiply(matrix1, matrix2):
    rows1, cols1 = len(matrix1), len(matrix1[0])
    rows2, cols2 = len(matrix2), len(matrix2[0])

    if cols1 != rows2:
        raise ValueError("Matrices dimensions are not suitable for multiplication")

    result = [[0 for _ in range(cols2)] for _ in range(rows1)]

    for i in range(rows1):
        for j in range(cols2):
            for k in range(cols1):
                result[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j]

    return result

def mesh_network_multiply_worker(args):
    row, col, matrix1, matrix2 = args
    result = 0
    for k in range(len(matrix1[0])):
        result += matrix1[row][k] * matrix2[k][col]
    return result

def mesh_network_matrix_multiply(matrix1, matrix2,num_processors):
    rows1, cols1 = len(matrix1), len(matrix1[0])
    rows2, cols2 = len(matrix2), len(matrix2[0])

    if cols1 != rows2:
        raise ValueError("Matrices dimensions are not suitable for multiplication")

    result = [[0 for _ in range(cols2)] for _ in range(rows1)]

    jobs = []
    for i in range(rows1):
        for j in range(cols2):
            jobs.append((i, j, matrix1, matrix2))

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_processors) as pool:
        results = pool.map(mesh_network_multiply_worker, jobs)

    for (i, j), value in zip([(i, j) for i in range(rows1) for j in range(cols2)], results):
        result[i][j] = value

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_cases_change_matrices = 5
    test_cases_change_num_of_processors = 3

    # Generate random test cases to see the alorithm effectiveness
    for i in range(test_cases_change_matrices): # change matrices
      print(f'Case {i+1}:')
      random_row_1 = random.randint(1, 1000)
      random_col_1 = random.randint(1, 1000)
      random_row_2 = random_col_1
      random_col_2 = random.randint(1, 1000)
      print(f'  Martix 1 dimension: [{random_row_1},{random_col_1}]')
      print(f'  Martix 2 dimension: [{random_row_2},{random_col_2}]')
      matrix1 = generate_random_matrix(random_row_1, random_col_1)
      matrix2 = generate_random_matrix(random_row_2, random_col_2)
      for j in range(test_cases_change_num_of_processors): # with the same matrices and change num_processors only
        num_processors = random.randint(1, 4)
        print(f'    Number of processors: {num_processors}')

        # Measure time for sequential multiplication
        start_time = time.time()
        seq_result = sequential_matrix_multiply(matrix1, matrix2)
        end_time = time.time()
        seq_time = end_time - start_time

        # Measure time for parallel multiplication
        start_time = time.time()
        mesh_result = mesh_network_matrix_multiply(matrix1, matrix2,num_processors)
        end_time = time.time()
        mesh_time = end_time - start_time

        # Display results and time comparison
        print("    Time taken for Sequential Multiplication: {:.6f} seconds".format(seq_time))
        print("    Time taken for Mesh Network Parallel Multiplication: {:.6f} seconds".format(mesh_time))
        print("    --------------------------------------------------------------------")
      print("------------------------------------------------------------------------")
```

and this is a sample output:

```
Case 1:
  Martix 1 dimension: [912,338]
  Martix 2 dimension: [338,389]
    Number of processors: 1
    Time taken for Sequential Multiplication: 23.686445 seconds
    Time taken for Mesh Network Parallel Multiplication: 18.046920 seconds
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    Number of processors: 1
    Time taken for Sequential Multiplication: 23.985855 seconds
    Time taken for Mesh Network Parallel Multiplication: 18.130553 seconds
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    Number of processors: 1
    Time taken for Sequential Multiplication: 23.715991 seconds
    Time taken for Mesh Network Parallel Multiplication: 17.949234 seconds
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Case 2:
  Martix 1 dimension: [922,52]
  Martix 2 dimension: [52,162]
    Number of processors: 3
    Time taken for Sequential Multiplication: 2.595915 seconds
    Time taken for Mesh Network Parallel Multiplication: 1.739267 seconds
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    Number of processors: 3
    Time taken for Sequential Multiplication: 1.336910 seconds
    Time taken for Mesh Network Parallel Multiplication: 1.339813 seconds
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    Number of processors: 4
    Time taken for Sequential Multiplication: 1.360793 seconds
    Time taken for Mesh Network Parallel Multiplication: 1.381338 seconds
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Case 3:
  Martix 1 dimension: [857,98]
  Martix 2 dimension: [98,638]
    Number of processors: 2
    Time taken for Sequential Multiplication: 10.781560 seconds
    Time taken for Mesh Network Parallel Multiplication: 9.878194 seconds
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    Number of processors: 1
    Time taken for Sequential Multiplication: 9.205079 seconds
    Time taken for Mesh Network Parallel Multiplication: 9.638103 seconds
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    Number of processors: 2
    Time taken for Sequential Multiplication: 10.543083 seconds
    Time taken for Mesh Network Parallel Multiplication: 9.935939 seconds
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Case 4:
  Martix 1 dimension: [617,193]
  Martix 2 dimension: [193,355]
    Number of processors: 4
    Time taken for Sequential Multiplication: 7.288309 seconds
    Time taken for Mesh Network Parallel Multiplication: 7.904044 seconds
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    Number of processors: 4
    Time taken for Sequential Multiplication: 7.199606 seconds
    Time taken for Mesh Network Parallel Multiplication: 7.791511 seconds
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    Number of processors: 2
    Time taken for Sequential Multiplication: 7.198328 seconds
    Time taken for Mesh Network Parallel Multiplication: 7.522303 seconds
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Case 5:
  Martix 1 dimension: [125,483]
  Martix 2 dimension: [483,237]
    Number of processors: 4
    Time taken for Sequential Multiplication: 2.496729 seconds
    Time taken for Mesh Network Parallel Multiplication: 2.137040 seconds
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    Number of processors: 3
    Time taken for Sequential Multiplication: 2.549355 seconds
    Time taken for Mesh Network Parallel Multiplication: 3.647234 seconds
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    Number of processors: 4
    Time taken for Sequential Multiplication: 2.560537 seconds
    Time taken for Mesh Network Parallel Multiplication: 2.222813 seconds
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I expect getting smaller time as the number of cores increases, but the opposite happens.

Comment: there is an overhead to using processors, so using "more" is not necessarily faster (depending on what the code does).